# vim doesn't move to expected line

Tags: vim

My final goal is to split a text on sentence delimiters. However it shouldn't be split in sentences, but in chunks ca. 1000 lines and plus the rest of the current sentence. But in the experiment below I use only 2 lines for simplicity.

Consider the following text in a VIM buffer:

```
line 1. line 1. line 1.
line 2. line 2. line 2.
line 3. line 3. line 3.
line 4. line 4. line 4.
line 5. line 5. line 5.
```

After execution of:

```
:2 | exec 'normal! )hvgg' | exec "'<,'>w /tmp/part1.txt" | exec 'normal! gvd'
```

The result is as expected. Buffer contains:

```
line 2. line 2.
line 3. line 3. line 3.
line 4. line 4. line 4.
line 5. line 5. line 5.
```

But after the next run

```
:2 | exec 'normal! )hvgg' | exec "'<,'>w /tmp/part2.txt" | exec 'normal! gvd'
```

buffer contains:

```
line 2.
line 3. line 3. line 3.
line 4. line 4. line 4.
line 5. line 5. line 5.
```

What's going on here? Why doesn't it move to the second line which is `line 3. line 3. line 3.` ?

But I would expect the following text remain in the buffer

```
line 3. line 3.
line 4. line 4. line 4.
line 5. line 5. line 5.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've finally come to the accepted solution. Thanks to @B Layer for cooperation (e.g. mentioning that `w` command only writes full lines to a file). I've upvoted your answer.

```
:let i=1
:1000 | exec 'normal! )hvggd' | exec 'if i<10 | let num="0" . i | else | let num=i | endif' | call writefile(split(@@, "\n", 1), '/tmp/test' . num . '.txt') | let i=i+1
```

After that repeat the command by pressing `@:` if the last chunk is shorter than 1000 lines you'll get an error. Just save the rest manually.

After 5 executions I had as expected:

```
$ wc -l /tmp/test*.txt
  1001 /tmp/test01.txt
  1000 /tmp/test02.txt
  1001 /tmp/test03.txt
  1006 /tmp/test04.txt
  1001 /tmp/test05.txt
```

For those who want to use it I'll shortly explain the key steps:

`:1000`

Move to the line 1000 (chunks should be at least 1000 lines long)

```
exec 'normal! )hvggd'
```

Move to the begin of the next sentence and one char back so that the first char of the next sentence isn't deleted afterwards. To work properly on sentences which are spread over multiple lines `whichwrap=h,l` should be set, which isn't default as far as I know. Select everything from the current cursor position to the begin and delete it. The deleted content will be saved in the register.

```
call writefile(split(@@, "\n", 1), '/tmp/test' . num . '.txt')
```

Write the register contents (the chunk) to a file

I proceeded from the assumption that there won't be more than 99 chunks. If you need more, adjust the part related to padding as needed.

Comment: I'm glad you found something that works for the larger problem you were trying to address but I worry that future readers will be confused because _this does not answer the question being asked_. Your title is "vim doesn't move to expected line" and except for a bit of background at the beginning the entire post is a demonstration of the problem followed by these two questions (the only questions in the whole post): "What's going on here?" and "Why doesn't it move to the second line which is `line 3. line 3. line 3.`?"

Comment: ... [cont] Yes you mention a "final goal" at the start but you don't explicitly ask for a solution to it and you don't provide enough information to solve that anyways before devoting the vast majority of the post to one specific issue.

Answer (score 4):

The root of the problem is the `gv` at the end. It is unnecessary since the visual selection persists from the previous part of the command. Worse, it's not harmless because when you do `gv` when you're already in Visual mode [the current and previous Visual area are exchanged](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#gv). Meaning the previous selection is reselected!

Even though the previous selection was deleted the selection is applied to the same area...or at least what remains of it. In this case that would be the first of the remaining `line 2.` sentences.

To demonstrate, watch what happens when you enter this twice: `2G)hvgggvd`. This is exactly what's happening on the command line, minus the write to disk, but with 100% Normal mode commands.

So anyways we just need to lose the `gv` and this will work:

```
:2 | exec 'normal! )hvgg' | exec "'<,'>w! /tmp/part1.txt" | exec 'normal! d'
```

Beyond that there is a lot of noise in this command that can be cleaned up. Two of the `exec`s and accompanying quotes aren't necessary:

```
:2 | exec 'norm! )hvgg' | '<,'>w! /tmp/part1.txt | norm! d
```

**Update:** In response to one of your comments this...

```
'<,'>
```

is a linewise operation that selects from the first *line* of the last selected visual area to the last *line* of the same area. To get character wise ranges you need to use back-tics like this:

```
`<,`>
```

However, this won't work with `:w`...it's a linewise operation only.

***I'd point out that this is outside the scope of your question which asks why particular text is being deleted....so you might want to ask a separate question for characterwise write to file.***

**Update 2:** Here's a totally different approach to your problem...

Create a macro with the following command

```
:let @q = ")hs\<CR>\<ESC>k:let @a=@a+1\<CR>:1,.w /tmp/part\<C-R>a.txt\<CR>dgg"
```

- Run this command: `:let @a = 0`.
- Put the cursor on a sentence and, in Normal mode, run the macro with `@q`

This will behave the way you describe: the sentence and everything above it will be written to a file named `/tmp/part1.txt` and the saved text will be deleted. Now move to any other sentence and do `@q` again and this time the same thing will happen but it will write to `/tmp/part2.txt`. Each time you run the macro the file name will auto-increment. You can reset the index again with `:let @a = 0`.

***Like the previous update this is not addressing the actual question asked but because I'm nice I'm providing some extra help.*** (And OP still won't accept my answer.)

Comment: I get "E20: Mark not set" when I run your last command for the first time after opening the file. However after I re-run it (pressing up-arrow button and then ENTER) it works, but only once. The file contains expected number of lines. But all the subsequent executions put only one line into the file.

Comment: I use ":1000..." at the begin of the command. The rest is copied from your command. The first run creates a file '/tmp/part1.txt' with 1000 lines. All the subsequent runs overwrite the file, but it contains only one line after that.

Comment: E492: Not an editor command:  `<,`>w! /tmp/part1.txt | norm! d

There should be backtick characters before < and > which aren't displayed for some reason in the comment.

Comment: You can read it for yourself at `:h '<` and `:h '>`. I think you might need to create another question for this separate issue if you can't get it working. Oh, and read `:h mark-motions` to see difference between back and forward tics.

Comment: Ok. But it doesn't explain why there is only one line in the file instead of at least 1000.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out the answer to your original question and to write it all up....

Comment: I greatly appreciate your efforts. But unfortunately it didn't bring me further. If you solution works by you and not by me than it must be a bug in VIM, because I tried to be as exact as possible while describing my problem and steps.

Comment: I perfectly answered the exact (tough!) question you asked. But now you changed the scope to be any issue with your command. Despite that you haven't upvoted and only said thanks cuz I laid on the guilt. lol. I'll check back later today...I might be able to help then. I've been here for 1.5 hours, though, and I have a life.

Comment: I see the E20 now. It's not my revised command, your original command causes it, too. I'm not clear on how you intend to use this. You just want to manually place cursor on some sentence and run? How are the output file names chosen? You don't have anything that would increment from part1 to part2, for example. Is it just a manual process? What's the exact use case? You might need a totally different approach than you have (e.g. use a macro)...but outside of the primary problem that's been solved it's really not clear to me what your intent is.

Comment: Okay, I've written you a macro that will do everything you describe and then some (e.g. it auto-increments the output file name). It even writes out partial lines. That's pretty much all I have left to contribute to this one.